# Apex test Result - Stack Trace Error

Tags: apex

Any ideas why we are getting this Stack Trace error?
[image]

Comment: The correct method signature is `assertEquals(expected, actual, message)`. Your tests will be much less confusing if you put `expected` first.

Comment: +1 for actually posting the line numbers in the OP instead of making us guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the reason why the error looks weird (got 5, expected 0) is because you've reversed the arguments to System.assertEquals. You should place the expected value *first,* and the value you're testing *second.* In other words:

```
System.assertEquals(5, forecastToCheck.size());
```

Secondly, this error is simply saying your logic is wrong. On line 44, your query results had zero rows, which means that either your unit test failed to call some function, or your logic isn't working the way you expected. You'll need to backtrack further up your unit test and figure out why you're not getting any forecast lines created. Based on the name of the unit test, it may be that you failed to call Test.stopTest() to run some asynchronous code, or you didn't insert or update a record properly.

You'll probably want to open a new question that includes all of your unit test code so we can accurately figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will forward to our Sys. Admin. and see if that does the trick. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

In the query at line 43,you are specifying the opportunity Id for the record(oppsToCheck[0].Id).
In thi scase you get only one opp record as Id is unique.
So the assert statement fail because the size of result is 1 not 5.

Comment: The result was *zero*, not *one*. Furthermore, AllForecastLine__c is a child of opportunity, so there may indeed be *five* results.